# why does my VBA code always skip my 1st loop?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to make my VBA code loop through all my cells and lower the count of an already existing number in my 2nd sheet by 1 every time it encounters a specific text in a cell. However, whenever I run my loop in steps, it seems to be skipping the next j and goes directly to next i every time which is the next row. Is there some sort of formatting error with my code?

```
Sub DeleteSAC()

Dim count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Sheets(1).Select

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'have to keep data in a table for this to actually work as it ctrls+left to the table, which will end where the very last text of any row is
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column


count = Sheet2.Cells(1, 7).Value
i = 2
j = lastColumn

For i = 2 To lastRow
For j = lastColumn To 1
If Sheet1.Cells(i, j) = "SAC" Then
    count = count - 1
    GoTo NextIteration
End If
Next j
NextIteration:
Next i

Sheet2.Cells(1, 7) = count


End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of that “GoTo NextIteration”

Comment: To count down use `For j = lastColumn To 1 Step -1`

Comment: To break out of a loop, use `Exit For` rather than `GoTo`

Comment: And you could avoid both loops and use CountIf(): count = count - WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range(“A2”, Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)), “SAC”)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
    Option Explicit

        Sub DeleteSAC()

        Dim count As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim lastcolumn As Long

        Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")


        lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        lastcolumn = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        count = ws2.Cells(1, 7).Value
        i = 2
        j = lastcolumn


        For i = 2 To lastRow
        For j = lastcolumn To 1 Step -1


        If ws1.Cells(i, j) = "SAC" Then
            count = count - 1
Exit for
            End If


        Next j
        Next i

        ws2.Cells(1, 7) = count


        End Sub
```